# How to use variable outside for() and foreach() in C#?

Tags: c#

I don't know how to get a result from for to use in the foreach loop.

My code like:

```
List<string> lstNameImage = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < lstImgAdded.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string imgPath = lstImgAdded.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;
    lstNameImage.Add(imgPath);
}
foreach (var items in lstNameImage)
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(items[0].ToString());       // how to using img in before for loop?
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `imgPath` instead of `img` in your comment? If so, `items` will already contain that information. Change your code to `Image img = Image.FromFile(items);`

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593540/access-variable-inside-while-loop-from-outside-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the below line

```
string imgPath = lstImgAdded.Items[i].SubItems[getRows].Text;
```

To just

```
string imgPath = lstImgAdded[i];
```

In `foreach` item variable already contains the list item what you are trying to get and so passing item would suffice

```
foreach (var item in lstNameImage)
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(item);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
foreach (var items in lstNameImage)
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(item);   
}
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
foreach (int index = 0; index < lstNameImage.Count; index++)
{
    var item = lstNameImage[index];
    Image img = Image.FromFile(item);   
}
```

Hence Rahul's solution.